# What is the best (safest) way to rename WPF file names in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, rename

When working with Visual Studio, is there a  recommended way for renaming and moving files as to not cause any issues where Visual Studio gets confused and doesn't think that certain files exist?

Comment: I tried updating it so that maybe someone will understand what I'm asking

Comment: You were downvoted because most people on SO want an easy question to answer and will downvote when they don't get that. The issue with your post is that, as originally written, was too encompassing, too wordy to solve. Its a valid question in its essence, but SO is (IMHO) not a kind place for beginners to ask questions to *learn*.  You did the right thing w/your post and for future reference, keep it to one issue which is reproducible and to the point. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Rename

1. Rename **one** Xaml/CS file presented in visual studio.
2. In the .cs file change the name of the class which contains the page/control.
3. In the xaml file change the name control/page to the new name.
4. **Build and run to verify.**

#### Move

1. Move **one** set of both the cs and xaml file to the new location.
2. In the .cs file change the namespace to match the folder namespace.
3. In the .Xaml file change the namespace to match the folder namespace.
4. In all other xaml files (one at a time) which reference the page/control, adjust the current namespace to contain the new namespace change. If the namespace is used by others, skip and go to step 5.
5. (In xaml) Add a new namespace to the top of the xaml file which references the page/control such as `NewControls:...`. *Visual Studio Intellisense should help you on fully qualifying the pathing*.
6. (In Xaml) Change the preceding namespace on the control/page as needed such as `controls:...` to `NewControls:...` and where the control is instantiated change the `controls` prefix to the new such as `NewControls.MyControl`.
7. **Build and run to verify**.
8. Repeat (go to step 4) for each other page reference.

#### App

If you made a change to the page which the application launches, go to the app.xaml and reference the new namespace/name as needed.